# How to set current Project version and Project build timstamp in a interface by using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a question concerning Maven. I have created a Jar file the name "MyFinalFarFileName_1.0.0-SNAPHOT_20140730.jar". Here is a small code snippet from my pom.xml file:

```
<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>   
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd</maven.build.timestamp.format>   
</properties>

<build>         
   <finalName>MyFinalJarFile_${project.version}_${timestamp}</finalName>

   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>
                    jar-with-dependencies
                </descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <source-jdk>1.6</source-jdk>
                    <target-jdk>1.6</target-jdk>
                </manifestEntries>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>myMainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>assembly-jar-Id</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Currently I´m set a manual build timestamp and project version number in a Java Interface like this:

```
public MyInterface {

    public String versionNumber = "My Project Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT";
    public String versionBuildTimeStamp = "My Project BuildTimeStamp: 20140730 11:34";
}
```

Is it possible to set these kind of information by using maven? Or it is necessary to create a propertie file with these kind of information by using maven and combine this popertie file with my Java Interface?

It is not enough to set this information in the manifest file of my created Jar file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look [here which describes four different approaches](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible however not at all suitable, better to write a maven plugin that will write these properties to a properties file and then you can fill in your constant values reading that properties file

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do this, take a look on the [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

The easiest way in your specific case could be to read a property file that is updated by the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) with the current version number and timestamp (it can process files and replace variables easily).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) can help you.